# react-aria useButton hook disabling accessibility functionality rather than supporting it

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, react-aria

I'm integrating the `react-aria` hook library into my codebase to ensure that my custom components properly meet all ARIA accessibility requirements. I've immediately noticed however that when I use the props generated by the library's `useButton` hook as described in the documentation, that a button which was focused with Tab no longer executes its `onClick` event on key press of Enter or Space, functionality that previously worked just fine before integration of the library.

The below sandbox illustrates the issue: Tabbing to the green button (the `RegularButton` component) and pressing Enter or Space will fire the `onClick` event and render the message. However, toggling to the red button (the `ButtonWithReactAria` component) and pressing Enter or Space will result in nothing happening.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/twilight-cloud-np66r3

Does anyone know what's causing this issue?

Comment: Does onClick still work on pointer click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/useButton.html#events)

> `useButton` supports user interactions via mouse, keyboard, and touch. You can handle all of these via the `onPress` prop. This is similar to the standard onClick event, but normalized to support all interaction methods equally.

So all you need to do is change the `onClick` prop passed to your `ButtonWithReactAria` component to `onPress`, and all will be well. See [this forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cold-paper-4ytdxk?file=/src/App.tsx:18,51) where I've done exactly that (and made no other changes), and the button now works as expected with both keybord and mouse.

(I notice this is a Typescript codesandbox so it's a fair question to ask why Typescript isn't preventing you using the wrong prop here. I can't answer that without delving quite deeply into the types involved, since I'm not personally very familiar with react-aria. It's certainly unfortunate that TS doesn't seem to protect you from this error. But I'm prioritising getting this answer out there!)